# SQL Select from records after given timestamp within other table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have make 2 Tables.
One is for messages and the other is for deleted_chats.
If someone delete the Chat then it should shows only the new messages after deleted timestamp

Please use these table/column names in your answer:

```
user_messages: user_id, chat_id, timestamp
user_chats_deleted: user_id, chat_id, timestamp
```

my SQL Code:

```
SELECT * FROM user_messages um

    LEFT JOIN (

SELECT *
FROM user_chats_deleted
GROUP BY timestamp Order by timestamp ASC Limit 1
)ud ON (um.chat_id = ud.chat_id and um.user_id = ud.user_id and ud.timestamp     < um.timestamp)

    where um.chat_id = '4' ORDER BY um.timestamp ASC
```

It shows messages but not how I want :/

Comment: `select * from user_messages where timestamp > (select timestamp from user_chats_deleted where chat_id = 4 order by timestamp desc limit 1) and chat_id = 4` maybe this will help

Comment: You should map user_messages id in user_chats_deleted as user_messages_id. This will be easier.

Comment: @abhishek This is the true way but It  doesnt work. Have Changed it to:

Comment: timestamp > EXISTS (select timestamp from user_chats_deleted where chat_id = '".$getChatid."' and user_id = '".$user->id."' order by timestamp DESC limit 1)

Comment: It doesnt select the timestamp of user chats deleted

Comment: what is the result of `select timestamp from user_chats_deleted where chat_id = '".$getChatid."' and user_id = '".$user->id."' order by timestamp DESC limit 1`

Comment: It shows all messages

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different queries you could try, though they should all do the same thing:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_messages um
 WHERE um.timestamp >
     ( SELECT MAX(um.timestamp)
         FROM user_chats_deleted ucd
        WHERE ucd.user_id = um.user_id
          AND ucd.chat_id = um.chat_id
     );
```

A cleaner and more readable/understandable SQL script:

```
 WITH Last_Deleted_Message AS
    ( 
      SELECT user_id
           , chat_id
           , MAX(timestamp) AS max_deleted_timestamp
        FROM user_chats_deleted ucd
       GROUP
          BY user_id
           , chat_id
     )
SELECT user_id
  FROM user_messages um
  JOIN Last_Deleted_Message ldm
    ON um.user_id = ldm.user_id
   AND um.chat_id = ldm.chat_id
   AND um.timestamp > ldm.max_deleted_timestamp
 WHERE um.chat_id = '4' 
 ORDER 
    BY um.timestamp ASC;
```